# Javascript: How can I access a function-scoped variable within a do while loop?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, do-while

This do while checks the user input. However, the console gives me an error, saying "size is not defined" which I think is because size is within the function whereas the while condition is outside the function

```
const newGrid = document.getElementById('new-grid');
newGrid.addEventListener('click', createGrid);

const main = document.querySelector('main');

function createGrid() {
    do {
        let size = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number from 1 to 64", ""), 10);

        const numPx = (600 / size) - 2;
        let px = numPx + 'px';

        for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                const div = document.createElement('div');
                div.setAttribute('class', 'grid');
                main.appendChild(div);
                div.setAttribute('style', `width: ${px}; height: ${px}`);
            }
        }

    } while(isNaN(size) || size > 64 || size < 1);

}
```

Comment: Don't use `isNaN`, use the less-error prone `Number.isNaN`.

Comment: @JaredSmith `size` is a number, so it shouldn't matter

Comment: It looks like everything from `const numPx` until the end of the `do` block should be placed *after* the `while` loop?!

Comment: @Bergi, yes, they should, I'm having another problem with the grid not printing out correctly, though I'm working on that part now.

Comment: @Bergi good habits are good habits. I still use `===` even when it doesn't matter.

Comment: @JaredSmith My good habits come down to thinking about the types my variables have, so I never use number functions on strings or compare two different types so I always can use `==` :-)

Comment: @Bergi works great until someone else unaware of your convention modifies your code. Unless you solve it with tooling (e.g. typescript, flow + precommit hook).

Answer (score 2):

You can declare the variable (`let size;`) within the function but outside the `do` block, then assign it (`size = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number from 1 to 64", ""), 10);`) within the `do` block .

Comment: @00Saad are you sure? You literally just have to have a single line that says `let size` above `do {` and remove the `let` after that line.

Comment: @vlaz I made a dumb mistake, the above user was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

- change it to var (const and let are block-scoped, vars are function-scoped and hoisted, more on that [here](https://hackernoon.com/js-var-let-or-const-67e51dbb716f))
- and more elegant  - change `let size` to `const size` (because you don't have to reassign it) and move it a level up like so:

  ```
  function createGrid() {
  const size = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a number from 1 to 64", ""), 10);
  ```

Comment: yup noticed right after I posted, just corrected it thanks